# Windows Form Application Crashes Immediately

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework

I have checked the CPU compile options and made sure Any CPU is set.  Here is the log from the event viewer.

```
Application: QuickBooks-Sync.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.ArgumentException
Stack:
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(System.String)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(System.String)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(System.String, System.String)
   at LSTQBEntities.QBEntities..ctor()
   at QuickBooks_Sync.Form1..ctor()
   at QuickBooks_Sync.Program.Main()
```

Comment: Please post the code in the Form1 constructor. Or, move everything besides InitializeComponent(); *out* of the Form1 constructor and have it execute in the form's OnLoad event - then wrap that code in a try/catch block.

Comment: maybe the LSTQBEntities.QBEntities constructor code could help too

Comment: There is nothing in my Form1 constructor (except for InitializeComponent())  & nothing in my load either.  The .exe runs fine on my development computer

Comment: You need to provide a little more information about what you're doing here... does the application load external DLLs (like some Quickbooks API or something)? Are those DLLs present on your machine but not the target machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a data provider that was not being installed via the installation package.  After installing the data provider everything was ok

Comment: In future, try using try-catch blocks to catch exceptions so that you can handle them. For example, you might output the error messages to a log file or the GUI, so that you can see why exactly the application is failing.